# prove that set of reals numbers and complex numbers are equipotent.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I have to prove that set of  reals R and set of complex C are equipotent. 
  " i know that set A and B are equipotent iff there is one to one mapping of A onto B. "
    please anyone give me answer of this...

Comment: You could think of $\Bbb C$ as $\Bbb R^2$. Do you know how to show $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^2$ have the same cardinality?

Comment: Can you find an injective map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$? Can you then also find an injective map from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$? Then use the Cantor-Schroeder-Berstein theorem.

Comment: yes this my problem,  i have to fail to find bijection between R and C. or
  an injection from R to C  and C to R.
 yes i know cantor- schroender -Berstein theorem but i fails in definition of mapping..

Comment: You should at least be able to find the first injection $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$. What do you think would be a reasonable choice for such a map?

Comment: Alternatively, if you know that $\mathbb R$ is equipotent with the set of subsets of $\mathbb N$, then you can prove this fairly directly from that result.

Comment: i think injection from R to C can be defined by
 f(x) = f(x + 0i) but i am not sure  about this.

Comment: I think you mean $f(x)=x+0i$ and you're right. That works because if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x+0i=y+0i$ which means that $x=y$ so $f$ is an injection. Can you find the injection going the other way? This direction is a bit more difficult so you may need to think about it (for topological reasons such a map can *not* be continuous so you won't be able to write it as a simple formula).

Comment: Thomas Andrews sir, yes i know that R is equipotent to power set of N ie P(N) but how could we prove from this that R and C are equipotent.

Comment: Daniel Rust sir,  i have difficulty to find other injection map from R to C , the map i know is as 
f(x) = x+ 0i  
  how to find other one,  please help me sir

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know that $\mathbb R$ is equipotent with $P(\mathbb N)$, the power set of $\mathbb N$, show the following lemmas:

> 1. For any set $X$,  $P(X\times\{1,2\})$ is equipotent with $P(X)\times P(X)$.
> 2. If $X$ is equipotent with $Y$ then $P(X)$ is equipotent with $P(Y)$.
> 3. $\mathbb C$ is equipotent with $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$.
> 4. $\mathbb N\times\{1,2\}$ is equipotent with $\mathbb N$.

The we get: $$\mathbb C\cong \mathbb R\times\mathbb R\cong P(\mathbb N)\times P(\mathbb N) \cong P(\mathbb N\times \{1,2\})\cong P(\mathbb N)\cong\mathbb R$$

Where we read $A\cong B$ as "$A$ is equipotent to $B$."

Comment: Thank you , Thomas Andrews sir,  it is a nice method

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ and $y$ be two real numbers and let $z$ be the complex number given by $x+iy$. Suppose the fractional part of $x$, $\lfloor x\rfloor$ has decimal expansion (always choose the greedy expansion which does not have a trailing string of $9$s) given by $0.x_1x_2x_3\ldots$ and let the natural number $|n_x|$ be such that $n_x+\lfloor x\rfloor =x$. Similarly let $n_y+\lfloor y\rfloor =y$.

We define $g\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $$g(z)=g(x+iy) = \epsilon_x \epsilon_y \underbrace{11\ldots 11}_{|n_x|} \underbrace{00\ldots00}_{|n_y|}.x_1y_1x_2y_2x_3y_3\ldots x_iy_i\ldots$$ where $\epsilon_x=0$ if $x$ is non-negative and $2$ if $x$ is negative, and $\epsilon_y=0$ if $y$ is non-negative and $3$ if $y$ is negative.

As an example, consider the complex number $w=x+yi=\pi-8.689i$. From the definition we need to know
$$\begin{array}{rcl}\lfloor x\rfloor & = & 14159265359\ldots\\
\lfloor y\rfloor& = &6891\\
n_x & = & 3\\
n_y & = & 8\\
x & \geq & 0\\
y & < & 0\end{array}$$
and so

$$\begin{array}{rcl}g(w) & = & 311100000000.1648195090206050305090\ldots\end{array}$$

I leave you to verify that this is an injective function. The rest of the necessary steps were covered in the comments, namely finding an injection $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ and then making use of the Cantor-Schroender-Berstein theorem.

Comment: Daniel Rust sir,  please explain the definition of functuon you have defined from C to R please also clarify which injection we have to defined from R to C other than f(x) = x + 0i

Comment: You only need one injection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ for the CSB theorem. I feel like the definition of the function $g$ in my answer is pretty explicit. You take the decimal expansion of your two real number (the components of the complex number), interleave the fractional parts of each, and then adding a certain number of $0$s and $1$s to the integer part of this fractional part which depends on the absolute value of the integer parts of the input numbers, you then also need $\epsilon_x$ and $\epsilon_y$ to distinguish between negative and non-negative inputs.

Comment: I've added an example so you can see maybe more clearly how $g$ acts on a complex number.

Comment: thank you so much Daniel Rust sir,  for adding example.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

This is equivalent to proving that $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are equipotent.

Consider the following mapping  $\pi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R^2}$

We take $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and we write it in binary notation (this works in any base, but binary makes it simpler):

$a = a_n 2^n + a_{n-1}2^{n-1} + \ldots + a_0 2^0 + b_12^{-1}+b_22^{-1}\ldots$

(we donsider $a_t = 0$ for $t > n$)

Then we construct $(b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ as follows:

$$b = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{2k}2^k + b_{2k+2}2^{-k}$$

$$c = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{2k+1}2^k + b_{2k+1}2^{-k}$$

It's quite easy to prove that it's both injective and exhaustive. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: One should be careful that the choice of binary representation is unique, as the binary numbers $1$ and $0.111\ldots$ are equal.

Comment: Yes, one should only use the former as you pointed out on your answer. I think it still works if you only use the other representation as long as you don't mix them.